# Random Sampling From Histogram/Frequency Hash Table

Tags: random, common-lisp, histogram, sample

I am currently trying to come up with a semi-decent (considering complexity, statistical properties and common sense) algorithm for sampling.

The data is currently contained inside a hash table, where each key is an item and the key's value is the item's frequency in the original distribution.

If one wanted to sample from such histogram, how would he go about doing that if he wanted to preserve the original probabilities of the items and transfer them into the sample?

Also, we require that there is a flag of whether duplicate items are allowed in the sample. In the case of not allowing the duplicates, the best I came up with is to apply the algorithm from the paragraph above and delete the item from the hash table once it is sampled. This way, at least the relative probabilities are preserved amongst the remaining items. However, I am unsure of whether this is an accepted practice statistically.

Is there a generally accepted algorithm for doing this? If it helps, we need to implement it in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

This is a part of the answer. It uses lists instead of hash table:

```
(defun random-item-with-prob (prob-item-pairs) 
  "The argument PROB-ITEM-PAIRS is ((p_1 item_1) (p_2 item_2) ... 
   (p_n item_n)). The function returns one of the items according to the
   probabilities. "
 (loop with p = (random 1.0)
       with x = 0
       for pair in prob-item-pairs
       do
        (if (< p (+ (first pair) x)) 
            (return (second pair))
            (incf x (first pair)))))
```

For the second part of your question: If you want to sample according to frequencies, this means that you care about the distribution of the data. Removing items (or not allowing duplicates) alters the distribution *during* the sampling procedure. If you really want to do that, you can repeat calls to the previous function, removing duplicates until you have the desired sample size.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with continuing to call the function while removing duplicates it may possibly return is that it one can easily envision a situation for which this can take a really long time. For instance, the following dictionary `("a": 99, "b" : 1)` with the condition to sample `n=2` could take a long time.

Comment: There is probably a way to emulate this, along the lines of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling